# How can I tell selenide to refesh a page in between retries without raising an error?

Tags: selenium, kotlin, selenide

I want to test a feature that requires a pageload to be updated. Since selenide only checks if the element has appeared without reloading the page, it will not pick up on the updated state.

I am currently doing it like this:

```
element(byAttribute("type", "submit")).click()
try {
    element(byText("some specific text")).shouldBe(visible)
} catch (e: com.codeborne.selenide.ex.ElementNotFound){
    refresh()
    element(byText("some specific text")).shouldBe(visible)
}
```

This is bad in multiple ways:

- it catches an error, which is not intended to be caught (otherwise it would have been an exception)
- it triggers side effects, like creating error-screenshots
- it only retries exactly once
- it waits the full first timeout, which may not even be needed. e.g. maybe it could have refreshed immediately then be successful

in case you are wondering: the feature in question is related to a cache being warm or cold. Forcing the cache to be cold at the beginning of the test would probably be possible, but it would also add a lot of complexity (e.g. interacting directly with the database), which I would like to avoid.

Comment: some context about selenide's error-handling https://selenide.org/2019/12/02/advent-calendar-how-to-abuse-selenide/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with selenide, but I think you can fix at least several problems you listed with the following changes:

1. Put the `try-catch` block inside a `while true` loop so as if the element found visible `break` is applied, otherwise continue looping.
   In case you want to avoid infinite loop add some counter there so that in case after X iterations the element was not found visible - leave it.
2. Decrease the timeout for waiting for the expected condition. You did not share here where you define if, so I don't know how to change that.
   The first paragraph changes could be something like the following:

```java
element(byAttribute("type", "submit")).click()
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    try {
        element(byText("some specific text")).shouldBe(visible)
        break
    } catch (e: com.codeborne.selenide.ex.ElementNotFound){
        refresh()
        element(byText("some specific text")).shouldBe(visible)
    }
}
```

Comment: selenide's `shouldBe` essentially already does what you are suggesting (retrying a lot of times with a small timeout inbetween), so I was hoping there would be some simple way to modify selenide's behavior without too much work around it. At this point I guess dropping selenide for this one check would be reasonable too, since it is basically just a wrapper around selnium that adds the retrying-thing.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, as I said, I'm not familiar with selenide...